# Firebase item quantity and availability

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build an app for a store selling mobile phones, but **limited quantities.**

So I want to show the customer the remaining quantity of an item. to show as a text view or something

and I want to check on my database who ordered the item

**so when someone buys a mobile phone he can see the remaining quantity of an item, and I can see on my database his ID or name**

I only linked my app with firebase. whats next ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: just store the total quantity below a node into your Firebase database structure and then for each sell or button press decrement that number by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more precise to what you're asking but as the broader answer for your question, I can suggest you to have a specific node with the device name and it's quantity as the value.

So the database structure would look something like this:

```java
availableDevices
|
 - device1: numberLeft
 - device2: numberLeft
 .
 .
 .
```

When you get a particular order of a device, you can subtract the `numberLeft` value from the device node.

Also you can keep track of who ordered which device, by having a node with `customers` and then giving the value of device they bought as the value.

So the database would look something like this:

```java
customers
|
 - customer1
 | 
  - deviceOrderedRecently: deviceName
  - numDevicesOrderedUntilNow: number
 |
  - customer2
  .
  .
  .
```

This should give you a bit of direction and inspiration to build your app ahead.

Comment: Thank you dear
i'm still learning firebase so , im gonna search how to make my database like you did above

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)